# Can MySQL automatically and transparently de-duplicate strings?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

In C, the compiler assigns `"strings"` numeric IDs (4-byte pointers) and only keeps one copy of each string: for `char *a="Hello", *b="Hello";`, only one copy of `"Hello"` is stored in memory. This is totally automatic and transparent to the user.

My question is whether MySQL can do the same, i.e, de-duplicate strings automatically and transparently to the user.

Ideally, I would expect it to be an internal storage mechanism of the database, so that (as in case of C) for the user the database would look and behave completely as if it contained actual strings, while in implementation it would only contain pointers.

In my database there are many repeating strings, like this:

```
`unit`, `building`, `office`, `firstName`, `lastName`

Chicago main production unit    | headquarters | accounting | Jane | Smith
Chicago main production unit    | office       | sales      | Jane | Dow
Miami administrative department | headquarters | sales      | Mary | Smith
Miami administrative department | office       | accounting | Mary | Dow
```

etc. where strings like `'Miami administrative department'` or `'accounting'` or `'Smith'` are repeated many times in different records.

This increases the size of the database, so that I hit hosting limitations.

An obvious solution is data normalization: to maintain a separate table for names

```
`id`, `string`

1 | Chicago main production unit
2 | Miami administrative department
3 | headquarters
4 | accounting
5 | Jane
6 | Smith
7 | office
8 | sales
9 | Dow
```

and then have my table as

```
`unit_id`, `building_id`, `office_id`, `firstName_id`, `lastName_id`

1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
1 | 7 | 8 | 5 | 9
```

and translate all strings on input and output. But of course this is very cumbersome.

My question is whether MySQL can do it automatically and transparently for the user: whenever I INSERT a row, it would automatically update the table of strings and only store the ids instead of strings in the table, and same for DELETE, WHERE, etc., so that to the user the table would look exactly the same as if it had strings, but occupy less space.

Comment: It sounds like you want to normalize your database, so you have multiple entities.  Offhand, you seem to have a locations entity and a persons entity.  SQL handles this by using data modeling to create the right data model for the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, I will look into normalization. No, the structure that I describe is just and example; in my application I have document titles, individual words in those documents, morphological forms of those words, types of the document, etc.

Comment: Some RDBMSes have features that do similar things—for example, [page compression in recent versions of SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1582/implementing-data-compression-in-sql-server-2008/) will transparently compress repeated row data across a page using dictionary compression, which isn't a million miles away from C string pooling, conceptually. I'd imagine most servers aim for "fast" over "small", though, in general, and leave you to decide how to best normalise your data manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is whether MySQL can do the same.

Although you can certainly achieve the desired result (it is called *data normalization*) MySQL does not do it implicitly.

> Can MySQL do it automatically and transparently for the user?

No, MySQL cannot do it automatically for you - you have to do it yourself. You need to be explicit about it in your queries and DDL statements.

Here is a short demo to show how you can create a lookup table, and then use it in your inserts and selects:

```
create table lookup(id int, name varchar(10));
create table data(id int, id_lookup int);
insert into lookup(id,name) values (1,'quick');
insert into lookup(id,name) values (2,'brown');
insert into lookup(id,name) values (3,'fox');

insert into data (id, id_lookup)
values (110, (select id from lookup where name = 'quick'));
insert into data (id, id_lookup)
values (120, (select id from lookup where name = 'brown'));
insert into data (id, id_lookup)
values (130, (select id from lookup where name = 'quick'));
insert into data (id, id_lookup)
values (140, (select id from lookup where name = 'fox'));
```

Now `data` has these rows:

```
110 1
120 2
130 1
140 3
```

To select the name, you need to join to your `lookup` table:

```
select d.id, t.name
from data d
join lookup t on t.id=d.id_lookup
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb3eb/2)

Note: it is uncommon to create a lookup table for all your strings. Commonly you would create a separate lookup table for each kind of strings (i.e. `unit_lookup`, `building_lookup`, and so on) or to partition your lookup table with a special lookup code column:

```
id code name
-- ---- ----
 1 unit Chicago
 2 unit Miami
 3 bldg Headquarters
 4 bldg Office
```

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I meant in my question by the obvious solution. Do I understand correctly that the answer to the question is plainly "no," MySQL will not do it for me transparently? I can do it myself, as you (and I) describe, but no specific help from the language? What I hoped on was some attribute on the table, and voila.

Comment: To clarify: my question was not whether _I myself_ can do it in MySQL, but whether _MySQL_ can do it for me, as C does. The answer is plainly no, right?

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh No, there's no magic, in MySQL or any major SQL engine, that would automate this. If you try to think through what an RDBMS would need to do in order to implement this transparently, you would quickly run into logical problems. For example, what would it do if you were to update string `Office` to `Ufficio` in one of the rows? Should it become the same in all your other rows referring to `Office`? What should happen when you delete the last containing a particular value?

Comment: A major difference between what I expected and data normalization is, for example, in `INSERT INTO table VALUES ((110, 'quick'),(120, 'brown'),(130, 'quick'));` (100,000 values here), which is impossible with data normalization? or is it? The user connects to the server over slow network, and 100,000 separate queries becomes a problem.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh Populating 100,000 rows is not a big deal for RDBMS. As long as you do not do it often (reference data rarely changes) the speed of your connection should matter much at all.

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight: I see no problem in the database doing it automatically. When I update one row to `Ufficio`, it should insert `'Ufficio'` in its internal name table and update this one row, EXACTLY AS IF it were storing a string. The name table should contain reference counts, and when the reference count comes to zero, the value is deleted. Unix file system does this with no problem (I mean hard links). Delayed copy on change for strings in programming languages does this with no problem.

Comment: Accepting the answer. I still suggest to change `Of course it can - it is called *data normalization"` to `No it cannot, but you can do it yourself - it is called *data normalization"`.

Comment: It wouldn't take any magic for a database system to do this. It would take a hashtable and a reference count. I'd be surprised if no databases does it.